# Why am I suddenly getting unresolved external symbols referencing my game engine from game project

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, unresolved-external, tinyxml

I've recently started building a game engine and a couple of game demos to help build up the engine, so at this stage it is still VERY simple. The engine is built as a static lib and linked to the game project. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

A few hours ago I attempted to add the TinyXML source files to my engine. Engine built fine, but when I built the project I started getting unresolved external symbols from my main.cpp referencing functions in my engine that have worked since I started it:

```
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class AshEngine::SystemManager & __cdecl AshEngine::SystemManager::GetInstance(void)" (?GetInstance@SystemManager@AshEngine@@SAAAV12@XZ) referenced in function _main
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall AshEngine::SystemManager::Start(class AshEngine::AshGame *,char const *,int,int)" (?Start@SystemManager@AshEngine@@QAE_NPAVAshGame@2@PBDHH@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Game* game = new Game();
    bool success = AshEngine::SystemManager::GetInstance().Start(game, "Monopoly", SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried rebuilding, cleaning, restarting PC, double checking the lib inclusion, adding both the lib folder to VCC directories AND specifying the lib directly in "Additional Dependencies". I've reversed all my changes (manually as I don't have source control on my PC - something I will now fix :/), I've tested it on 3 game demo projects using the same engine, and I've created a new project using the engine, and they all have the same problem.

When I turn on verbose linker logging, I noticed that my engine lib comes up under "Unused libraries". I tried turning on /OPT:NOREF linker flag but it didn't help.

I am at a loss as to why it cannot find these 2 symbols. Somehow I've broken my engine when adding TinyXML. I have a feeling I nuked all my preprocessor definitions when I tried to add TIXML_USE_STL to 'All Configurations'. I've readded WIN32, _DEBUG, and _CONSOLE, but not sure what else there might have been. I will definitely be installing source control after this so I can revert changes.

In the meantime, how can I figure out why my project can't find these symbols?

Comment: Where is `AshEngine::SystemManager::GetInstance` implemented?

Comment: Lol Raymond - it's implemented inside a PLATFORM_WIN32 ifdef.... which was nuked when I accidentally nuked my preprocessor definitions.... re-added and all is well now. Thanks for making me look there. 3 hours down the drain :(

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the symbols were inside an #ifdef which I had accidentally deleted from preprocessor definitions /facepalm